# @property in my AppDelegate becomes null when app goes to background in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my AppDelegate I have a property. It is strong and of type custom class(which is a subclass of NSObject). It becomes NULL when the App goes to background. This behaviour is uncertain and could not be reproduced easily (even with Simulate Memory Warning option). It occurs randomly.

My understanding is, when the app goes to background and if some other app needs memory, the app will be terminated. But in this case, the app is not terminated but a specific property becomes null.

I have not implemented didReceiveMemoryWarning in any of my ViewControllers.

Please help me with this.

**Edit:**

This is the sample of how my AppDelegate looks

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Person *person;//This is the custom class
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   // Override point for customization after application launch.
   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[UIViewController new]];
   self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: Show us your AppDelegate code.

Comment: @davidf2281 I have edited my question. Pls check out.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to override your property's setter and add a breakpoint in it. You will see when it has been set to `nil`.

Setter example:

```
- (void)setPerson:(Person *)person {
    _person = person; // breakpoint on this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didnt give us more informations and I do not know where do you set your Person object. But you should be sure it is not deleted in somewhere. For exmp: when you assign references to that object, the references can be gone.

Or if you want to keep that instance forever, you can use Keychain or NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think some other apps interefere your application allocation & deallocation. I think there is some memory leak in your application life cycle or may be some other object point your Person class weakly then deallocate your object when no-one point it when application goes into background state.

Answer (score 0):

If application terminated, person loose the person object so persist the object and fetch before you use that. for persisting you can use any database or file system like plist or user defaults.